# Average case lower bound for sorting

Tags: complexity-theory, sorting, lower-bounds

The $\Omega(n\lg{n})$ lower bound for sorting in the comparison model is well known.  Is there a similar average case lower bound for sorting in the comparison model and if so, which random distributions does it apply to?

Comment: You might want to look up Kolmogorov complexity, and more specifically average case analysis done with the incompressibility method. (It's a general proof method based on KC and random strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Sedgewick-Bentley talk ["QUICKSORT IS OPTIMAL"](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/talks/QuicksortIsOptimal.pdf) they give an (informal) proof that Quicksorts average case is optimal.

So the average case lower bound for sorting is $\Omega(n\lg{n})$.

Comment: By average case I mean over random input distributions.  I think you are referring to the average run time of a randomised algorithm which is something different.

Comment: @Lembik This is average case analysis over uniform input distributions.

Comment: That's a very nice reference. Thank you. "The average number of compares per element C/N is always within a constant factor of the entropy H"